# C++ STL Vector Memory Management When Initialized With Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, vector

If I initialize a vector with a dynamically allocated array, then later the vector goes out of scope and is to be freed, does the vector free the memory from the array that it is wrapping?
More specifically, say I have an example function:

```
std::vector<float> mem_test() {
    unsigned char* out = new unsigned char[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        out[i] = i * i;
    }
    std::vector<float> test_out(out, out + 10);
    return test_out;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<float> whatever = mem_test();

    // Do stuff with vector

    // Free vector
    std::vector<float>().swap(whatever);
}
```

When the vector returned from the function goes out of scope or is manually freed, will the underlying dynamically allocated array also have its memory freed?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  `test_out` doesn't even know what `out` is.

Comment: Remy already answered your question.  Just as an aside: I hope that is a demo example and you are not actually filling a vector by first creating an array with new and then copy the values to the vector.

Comment: @MikeMB I did specify it was an example function :3

Comment: Yes, but I'm not worried about the example function. I'm worried about the pattern the example demonstrates. Just wanted to make sure you are not actually using an intermediate dynamic array to initialize a vector.

Comment: @MikeMB I’m using stb_image.h (part of a fairly popular open source library) to load an image as an array, which is dynamically allocated. Then, wrapping it with a vector. Thus, I chose to demonstrate in the example function a simple dynamic array allocation. I feel like your worry seems to be out of scope for this question.

Comment: That's just it: You are not wrapping it, you are copying the data. That may still be a valid design choice in your case but probably not ideal. The way I'd demonstrate this in an example is by a function `foo(const float* bar )` or some such, which makes it clear that the origin of the pointer is outside of your control. But yes, this really becomes of topic.  Sorry I said something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does the vector free the memory from the array that it is wrapping?

The vector does not *wrap* the array at all.

> When the vector returned from the function goes out of scope or is manually freed, will the underlying dynamically allocated array also have its memory freed?

No. You are constructing the vector using a constructor that takes 2 iterators as input. It iterates through the source array *copying the values* of its elements into the vector's internal array. The source array itself is keep separate and must be `delete[]`'d explicitly before `mem_test()` exits or else it will be leaked.

```cpp
std::vector<float> mem_test() {
    unsigned char* out = new unsigned char[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        out[i] = i * i;
    }
    std::vector<float> test_out(out, out + 10);
    delete[] out; // <-- HERE
    return test_out;
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
std::vector<float> mem_test() {
    std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> out(new unsigned char[10]); // <-- auto delete[]'d
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        out[i] = i * i;
    }
    std::vector<float> test_out(out.get(), out.get() + 10);
    return test_out;
}
```